# Turn "Modified" shape into primary Physical shape?

Tags: modifiers

I'm working on a "Smart Watch" model. I used the "Shrinkwrap" modifier to create a rounded square for the shape of my watch case.

But when I import the shape into my game, It displays the original "unshrunk" box with sharp corners instead. The game's engine only recognizes original primary shapes, not the shape after modifiers have been applied.

Evidently, I need my "Shrinkwrapped" shape to be a "primary" (unmodified) object. Is there a way to do this?

[image: Blender]

(Please ignore outer texture transparency. That will be fixed.)
[image: Game]

TIA

Comment: try to apply the modifier before exporting, but maybe you'd better model the object without the help of shrinkwrap, how does the real object look like?

Comment: What format do you export to in your game engine ? Some exporters have an option to "Apply all modifiers" on export

Comment: Thx for replies. THAT WAS IT "Georgious"! Model must be exported to a Collada dae file. And there was indeed an "Apply modifiers" option. Huge thanks!